# How to make a "distinct" join with MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, distinct, left-join, subquery

I have two MySQL tables (product and price history) that I would like to join:

`Product` table:

```
Id = int
Name = varchar
Manufacturer = varchar
UPC = varchar
Date_added = datetime
```

`Price_h` table:

```
Id = int
Product_id = int
Price = int
Date = datetime
```

I can perform a simple LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT Product.UPC, Product.Name, Price_h.Price, Price_h.Date
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Price_h
ON Product.Id = Price_h.Product_id;
```

But as expected if I have more than one entry for a product in the price history table, I get one result for each historical price.

How can a structure a join that will only return one instance of each produce with only the newest entry from the price history table joined to it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use:

```
   SELECT p.upc,
          p.name,
          ph.price,
          ph.date
     FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN PRICE_H ph ON ph.product_id = p.id
     JOIN (SELECT a.product_id, 
                  MAX(a.date) AS max_date
             FROM PRICE_H a
         GROUP BY a.product_id) x ON x.product_id = ph.product_id
                                 AND x.max_date = ph.date
```

Comment: I understand why you say it should be faster, but I have yet to find a circumstance where it is.   I think it may have something to do with the large number of records I have in the price history table (3.5M).   Perhaps it would help if I added an index to the Price_h.date column?

Comment: It seems that this query takes approximately the same amount of time no matter how many results it returns whereas a1ex07's query takes longer with increased results, as would be expected.  I was just a little surprised at how slow this is for small result sets and how fast a1ex07's solution is for the same small results set.  Since in the "Real world"  I will be working with rather large result sets I have selected this as the answer.

Comment: You saved my day :), Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT Product.UPC, Product.Name, Price_h.Price, Price_h.Date
FROM Product
LEFT JOIN Price_h
ON (Product.Id = Price_h.Product_id AND Price_h.Date = 
  (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Price_h ph1 WHERE ph1.Product_id = Product.Id));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product.UPC, Product.Name, Price_h.Price, MAX(Price_h.Date)
 FROM Product
 INNER JOIN Price_h
   ON Product.Id = Price_h.Product_id
GROUP BY Product.UPC, Product.Name, Price_h.Price
```

Comment: That'd work but it wouldnt give him the correct price history entry that corresponds with the max(date)...

Comment: This query returns Max(date) for each (Product.UPC+Product.Name+Price_h.Price). It is not the latest price for the product.

Comment: Ariel and a1ex07 are correct.   This query does manage to return the correct date, but not the correct price.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT n.product_id, 
       n.product_name,
       n.product_articul,
       n.product_price,
       n.product_discount,
       n.product_description, 
       n.product_care,
       (SELECT photo_name FROM siamm_product_photos WHERE product_id = n.product_id LIMIT 1) AS photo_name
FROM siamm_product as n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep it simple and fast:

```
SELECT 
 Product.UPC, Product.Name, Price_h.Price, Price_h.Date
FROM 
 Product
LEFT JOIN 
 Price_h
 ON Product.Id = Price_h.Product_id;
ORDER BY
 Price_h.Date DESC
LIMIT 1
```